# Simulink logic to active output signal when variable is 2

Tags: matlab, simulink

How shall I activate signalA output signal when input signal value is 0 to 2.
Example: when input signal is 2, active output. 
When input signal is other than 2, reactive output.

Which means, when input signal value is from decending 5 to 2,output signal shall not active. Only need to active ascending 0 to 2 using simulink blocks